# How to Convert Row to Column in Linq and SQL

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

i have a table called **Languagemaster** having below record

```
language keyName keyValue
English    City    AA
Swedish    City    AAswedish
German     City    AAger
Chines     City    AAchines
French     City    AAfr
Spanish    City    AAspanish
```

how to convert **Languagemaster** Table to below table

```
keyName  English Swedish   German  Chines   French  Spanish            
City      AA     AAswedish AAger   AAchines AAfr    AAspanish
```

please let me know how to write Query in both  SOL and LinQ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ swap columns into rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950495/linq-swap-columns-into-rows)

Comment: Looks like you want to group columns by `keyName` value.

Answer (score 35):

**UPDATE**: I created following generic method which can build pivot table from any collection

```
public static DataTable ToPivotTable<T, TColumn, TRow, TData>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, TColumn> columnSelector,
    Expression<Func<T, TRow>> rowSelector,
    Func<IEnumerable<T>, TData> dataSelector)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    var rowName = ((MemberExpression)rowSelector.Body).Member.Name;
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(rowName));
    var columns = source.Select(columnSelector).Distinct();

    foreach (var column in columns)
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column.ToString()));

    var rows = source.GroupBy(rowSelector.Compile())
                     .Select(rowGroup => new {
                         Key = rowGroup.Key,
                         Values = columns.GroupJoin(
                             rowGroup,
                             c => c,
                             r => columnSelector(r),
                             (c, columnGroup) => dataSelector(columnGroup))
                     });

    foreach (var row in rows) {
        var dataRow = table.NewRow();
        var items = row.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();
        items.Insert(0, row.Key);
        dataRow.ItemArray = items.ToArray();
        table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Usage:

```
var table = Languagemaster.ToPivotTable(
                item => item.language,
                item => item.keyName,
                items => items.Any() ? items.First().keyValue : null);
```

It has three parameters:

- *column property selector* which selects columns (i.e. what will be in column headers) in your case it is distinct values of languages, but it could be anything else, like date.
- *row property selector* - is a value which will appear in row headers, this is a what each row will be related to. Keep in mind - it is expression, not simple delegate. We need it to set column name of first column.
- *data selector* - this is a method which will be run on grouped data for each cell. I.e. in your case we just select `keyValue` property of first item in group. But it could be items count `items => items.Count()` or anything else.

Result:

[image]

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

This query will return pivot for your data. Each item in query will have `Name` (i.e. "City" in your example) and list of values - one value for each pivot column (i.e. for each language we will have value containing language name as `Column` and `Value`)

```
var languages = Languagemaster.Select(x => x.language).Distinct();
var query = from r in Languagemaster
            group r by r.keyName into nameGroup
            select new {
                Name = nameGroup.Key,
                Values = from lang in languages
                         join ng in nameGroup 
                              on lang equals ng.language into languageGroup
                         select new {
                             Column = lang,
                             Value = languageGroup.Any() ? 
                                     languageGroup.First().keyValue : null
                         }
            };
```

How to build data table from this query

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("keyName");  // first column
foreach (var language in languages)
    table.Columns.Add(language); // columns for each language

foreach (var key in query)
{
    var row = table.NewRow();
    var items = key.Values.Select(v => v.Value).ToList(); // data for columns
    items.Insert(0, key.Name); // data for first column
    row.ItemArray = items.ToArray();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: I hope you plan to only use this for small datasets.

Comment: @AlW manipulating huge datasets in memory is not very good idea

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy what you recommend for huge datasets?

Comment: This works very well. 
Here is a code to group data based on multiple columns.

Comment: Genuinely brilliant.  Thank you.  Top marks for brains.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code to group data based on multiple columns.

```
        testDt = GetTestDate();
        var data2 = testDt.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => new
        {
            Family = x.Field<int>("tdFamily"),
            Class = x.Field<short>("luClass"),
            Region = x.Field<short>("luRegion"),
            Year = x.Field<int>("tdYear"),
            Population = x.Field<decimal>("tdPopulation ")
        });

        DataTable pivotDataTable = data2.ToPivotTable(
             item => item.Year,
            item => new{ item.Family, item.Class, item.Region},
            items => items.Any() ? items.Sum(x => x.Allocation) : 0
            );

         public static DataTable ToPivotTable<T, TColumn, TRow, TData>(
         this IEnumerable<T> source,
         Func<T, TColumn> columnSelector,
         Expression<Func<T, TRow>> rowSelector,
         Func<IEnumerable<T>, TData> dataSelector)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        var rowsName = ((NewExpression)rowSelector.Body).Members.Select(s => s).ToList();
        foreach (var row in rowsName)
        {
            var name = row.Name; 
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(name));
        }
        var columns = source.Select(columnSelector).Distinct();
        foreach (var column in columns)
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column.ToString()));
        var rows = source.GroupBy(rowSelector.Compile())
                         .Select(rowGroup => new
                         {
                             Key = rowGroup.Key,
                             Values = columns.GroupJoin(
                                 rowGroup,
                                 c => c,
                                 r => columnSelector(r),
                                 (c, columnGroup) => dataSelector(columnGroup))
                         });

        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            var dataRow = table.NewRow();
            var items = row.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();
            string[] keyRow = row.Key.ToString().Split(',');
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var key in keyRow)
            {
                string keyValue = key.Replace("}", "").Split('=')[1].Trim();
                items.Insert(index, keyValue);
                index++;
            }
            dataRow.ItemArray = items.ToArray();
            table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static DataTable XToPivotTable<T, TColumn, TRow, TData>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TColumn> columnSelector, Expression<Func<T, TRow>> rowSelector, Func<IEnumerable<T>, TData> dataSelector) {
      DataTable table = new DataTable();

      if (rowSelector.Body is NewExpression) {
        var rowNames = ((NewExpression)rowSelector.Body).Members.ToList();
        rowNames.ForEach(s => table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(s.Name, s.DeclaringType.GetProperty(s.Name).PropertyType)));
      } else {
        var rowName = ((MemberExpression)rowSelector.Body).Member;
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(rowName.Name, rowName.DeclaringType.GetProperty(rowName.Name).PropertyType));
      }

      var columns = source.Select(columnSelector).Distinct();

      foreach (var column in columns)
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column.ToString()));

      var rows = source.GroupBy(rowSelector.Compile())
        .Select(rg => new {
          rg.Key,
          Values = columns.GroupJoin(rg, c => c, r => columnSelector(r), (c, cg) => dataSelector(cg))
        });

      foreach (var row in rows) {
        var dataRow = table.NewRow();
        var items = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TRow)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().Select(s => s.GetValue(row.Key)).ToList();
        items.AddRange(row.Values.Cast<dynamic>());
        dataRow.ItemArray = items.ToArray();
        table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
      }

      return table;
    }
```