# How to change the data layout of a data table with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, datatable.select

[image]

Above is the screen shot of one of my Data Table. I am trying to transform this data into the following format so that I can bind it to one of my grid. I have tried LINQ but unsuccessful.
Could please anyone help me how I can do this. Doesn't necessarily be LINQ but I think it will be easier with LINQ

[image]

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to transform data?

Comment: First I am getting the Distinct Columns from "Object" as follow             var distinctColumnNames = dataSet.Tables["reportColumns"].AsEnumerable()
                .Select(row => new
                {
                    colObject = row.Field<string>("Object"),
                }).Distinct();

Comment: then I am running the following Linq statement foreach (var columnName in distinctColumnNames)
            {
                var dataRow = dataSet.Tables["reportColumns"].AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(rowData => new
                    {
                        colAttribute = rowData.Field<string>("Attribute"),
                        colValue = rowData.Field<string>("Value"),
                        colStandard = rowData.Field<int>("Standard")
                    });
            }

Comment: the bit I am missing is how to apply where clause in second statement (e.g. where dataRow.Object == "columnName"). I know i dont have the Object column selected over here but after selecting that column in dataRow how the where clause will be applied?

Comment: I have changed my second Linq Select statement and have added the "Object" column
foreach (var columnName in distinctColumnNames)
            {
                var dataRow = dataSet.Tables["reportColumns"].AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(rowData => new
                    {
                        colObject = rowData.Field<string>("Object"),
                        colAttribute = rowData.Field<string>("Attribute"),
                        colValue = rowData.Field<string>("Value"),
                        colStandard = rowData.Field<int>("Standard")
                    });
         }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below

```
var result =  dataSet.Tables["reportColumns"].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Object"))
    .Select(g => new
    {
        ColumnName = g.Key,
        DefaultColumn = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Field<string>("Attribute") == "DefaultColumn").Field<string>("Value"),
        Label = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Field<string>("Attribute") == "Label").Field<string>("Value"),
        Type = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Field<string>("Attribute") == "Type").Field<string>("Value"),
        Standard = g.FirstOrDefault().Field<int>("Standard")
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Damith. the result has brought a big smile on my face. Really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [ToPivotTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17972802/470005) extension:

```
public static DataTable ToPivotTable<T, TColumn, TRow, TData>(
      this IEnumerable<T> source,
      Func<T, TColumn> columnSelector,
      Expression<Func<T, TRow>> rowSelector,
      Func<IEnumerable<T>, TData> dataSelector)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    var rowName = ((MemberExpression)rowSelector.Body).Member.Name;
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(rowName));
    var columns = source.Select(columnSelector).Distinct();

    foreach (var column in columns)
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column.ToString()));

    var rows = source.GroupBy(rowSelector.Compile())
                     .Select(rowGroup => new
                     {
                         Key = rowGroup.Key,
                         Values = columns.GroupJoin(
                             rowGroup,
                             c => c,
                             r => columnSelector(r),
                             (c, columnGroup) => dataSelector(columnGroup))
                     });

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        var dataRow = table.NewRow();
        var items = row.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();
        items.Insert(0, row.Key);
        dataRow.ItemArray = items.ToArray();
        table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Create strongly-typed data from your source table:

```
var data = from r in table.AsEnumerable()
           select new {
                Object = r.Field<string>("Object"),
                Attribute = r.Field<string>("Attribute"),
                Value = r.Field<object>("Value")
           };
```

And convert them to pivot table:

```
var pivotTable = data.ToPivotTable(r => r.Attribute, 
                                   r => r.Object, 
                                   rows => rows.First().Value);
```

This will create pivot table with distinct values of *Attribute* (i.e. DefaultColumn, Label, Type) as columns, rows will be groups for each *Object* value, and each cell will have value of corresponding *Value* property for object group and attribute column.

---

Or in single query:

```
var pivotTable = table.AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(r => new {
                          Object = r.Field<string>("Object"),
                          Attribute = r.Field<string>("Attribute"),
                          Value = r.Field<object>("Value")
                      })
                      .ToPivotTable(r => r.Attribute, 
                                    r => r.Object, 
                                    rows => rows.First().Value);
```

Comment: Hi Lazyberezovsky, thank you very much for your reply. I haven't tried your sample code as I was already doing the LINQ way so decided to follow Damith approach and it worked for me.

Comment: @waseem this *is* a Linq way. And it does not requires three queries for each object group