# Swapping rows as a Columns

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have Datatable like below;

```
Systime       |   Name | Value
-----------------------------
 01.04.2017   Water       12
 01.04.2017   Bread       14
 01.04.2017   Chair       11
 02.04.2017   Water       25
 02.04.2017   Bread       16
 02.04.2017   Chair       21
```

and I want to swap rows with columns like below using linq or etc;

```
   systime | Water | Bread | Chair
-------------------------------
01.04.2017     12     14      11
02.04.2017     25     16      21
```

Comment: what you have tried

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel The problem is i don't know the way. Searched a lot but no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Convert Row to Column in Linq and SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971921/how-to-convert-row-to-column-in-linq-and-sql)

Comment: @kblok situations are different. I looked at and tried to apply but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you build your pivot table

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Systime", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("01/04/2017"),"Water", 12});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("01/04/2017"),"Bread", 14});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("01/04/2017"),"Chair", 11});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("02/04/2017"),"Water", 25});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("02/04/2017"),"Bread", 16});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("02/04/2017"),"Chair", 21});

            string[] items = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Name")).Distinct().ToArray();

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("Systime", typeof(DateTime));
            foreach(string item in items)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add(item, typeof(int));
            }

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Systime")).ToList();

            int index = 0;
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {

                DataRow newRow = pivot.Rows.Add();
                newRow[0] = group.Key;
                foreach (string item in items)
                {
                    newRow[item] = group.Where(x => x.Field<string>("Name") == item).Select(x => x.Field<int>("Value")).Sum();
                }
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works great. However, How can systime doesn't show up in grid and i see int index=0 and never used. Why is it there ?