# Pivot table and change DataTable format

Tags: c#, .net, linq, pivot, pivot-table

I'm pivoting a table using the method `ToPivotTable` and it works well
and I want to display the value with thousand separator like this ( 100 000,00) but I can't.
I tried to put `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]` in the model but didn't fix the problem.

My Model :

```
public class CompteResultat
    {

        public int CompteResultatID { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public Nullable<decimal>  Value { get; set; }
        public int IndicateurID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Year { get; set; }
        public virtual Indicateur Indicateur { get; set; }


    }
```

the Method :

```
  public static DataTable ToPivotTable<T, TColumn, TRow, TData>(
this IEnumerable<T> source,
Func<T, TColumn> columnSelector,
Expression<Func<T, TRow>> rowSelector,
Func<IEnumerable<T>, TData> dataSelector)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            var rowName = ((MemberExpression)rowSelector.Body).Member.Name;
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(rowName));
            var columns = source.Select(columnSelector).Distinct();
            foreach (var column in columns)
                table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column.ToString()));

            var rows = source.GroupBy(rowSelector.Compile())
                             .Select(rowGroup => new
                             {
                                 Key = rowGroup.Key,
                                 Values = columns.GroupJoin(
                                     rowGroup,
                                     c => c,
                                     r => columnSelector(r),
                                     (c, columnGroup) => (dataSelector((columnGroup).ToList())))
                             });
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {

                var dataRow = table.NewRow();
               
                var items = row.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();

                items.Insert(0, row.Key);

              
                dataRow.ItemArray = (items.ToArray());


                table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }

            return table;
        }
```

In the controller :

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
           
           
            var res = await context.CompteResultats.ToListAsync();


            
            var pivotTable = res.OrderBy(s=>s.Indicateur.Ordre).ToPivotTable(
              item => item.Year,
              item => item.Indicateur.Designation,

              items => items.Any() ? items.Sum(x =>(x.Value)) :0);

            return View(pivotTable);
        }
```

In the view :

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@using System.Data
 <table class="display table table-striped" id="myDatatable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                                                {
                                                    <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                                                }

                                            </tr>
                                            @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                                                    {
                                                        <td>
                                                            @row[col.ColumnName]
                                                        </td>

                                                    }
                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        </table>
```

For me the result is like this:

```
Indicateurs   2018         2019
Indicateur1   20000,00     68000,00
Indicateur2   50000,00     52000,00
```

and i want to display it like this :

```
Indicateurs   2018          2019
Indicateur1   20 000,00     68 000,00
Indicateur2   50 000,00     52 000,00
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I would like to copy and paste your code, then run it to see what you're seeing. Please give me the precise instructions to set it up.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity, I edited my post, hope it's understandable now.

Comment: Where did `ToPivotTable` come from?

Comment: @NetMage  I took the method 'ToPivotTable' from this link : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971921/how-to-convert-row-to-column-in-linq-and-sql)