# Rotate - Transposing a List<List<string>> using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, pivot-table, transpose

I'm having a `List<List<string>>`, which is return from the remote data source (i.e., WCF). So, I need to modify the following data into a user-friendly list using LINQ

The C# Code is

```
List<List<string>> PersonInfo = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>() {"John", "Peter", "Watson"},
    new List<string>() {"1000", "1001", "1002"}
}
```

Appropriate Screen Shot: **Existing**

[image]

I need to rotate the data as like the below Screenshot: **Proposed**

[image]

Kindly assist me how to rotate the data using **LINQ C#**

Comment: Are there always going to be two lists inside the main one?

Comment: @vmutafov Yes. `List<List<string>>`

Comment: The question is: does PersonInfo always contain 2 lists, or can there be more than 2?

Comment: I am not sure you understood me. I meant, are there always going to be one list with the names and one list with the numbers?

Comment: Just googled fo **c# rotate 2d list linq**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950495/linq-swap-columns-into-rows

Comment: This is called *transposing* rather than *pivoting* by the way.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a simple and flexible solution, it will handle multiple inner lists with any number of dimensions.

```
List<List<string>> PersonInfo = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>() {"John", "Peter", "Watson"},
    new List<string>() {"1000", "1001", "1002"}
};


var result = PersonInfo
    .SelectMany(inner => inner.Select((item, index) => new { item, index }))
    .GroupBy(i => i.index, i => i.item)
    .Select(g => g.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I realize this might revive this thread, but being not wholly familiar with this segment of VB.net, I was wondering if it would be possible to interject a Nothing or similar placeholder value if the input lists are uneven?

Comment: @pmackni That's entirely possible.  I'd say it's worth a separate question though - how you can convert a jagged array to a rectangular array, filling gaps with a specific value.

Comment: Surprised that this works (it does)! 

It depends heavily on the implementation of `GroupBy`, in the sense that it guarantees to preserve the [order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) of the groups and also the order of the elements within the groups! 

That said, I think you can omit the to `.ToList()` calls, 
as the `IEnumerable`s are [arrays under the hood](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L2298).

Comment: @3dGrabber The `.ToList()` calls are to satisfy the types specified in the question.  They're not required for transposing, for that only, you can lose the last two lines altogether.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a generic extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Pivot<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    var enumerators = source.Select(e => e.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
    try
    {
        while (enumerators.All(e => e.MoveNext()))
        {
            yield return enumerators.Select(e => e.Current).ToArray();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Array.ForEach(enumerators, e => e.Dispose());
    }
}
```

so you can

```
var result = PersonInfo.Pivot();
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are only ever 2 lists inside `PersonInfo`:

```
var rotated = PersonInfo[0]
    .Zip(PersonInfo[1], (a, b) => new List<string> { a, b }).ToList();
```

If there can be any number of Lists inside of PersonInfo:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, PersonInfo[0].Count)
    .Select(i => PersonInfo.Select(lst => lst[i]).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Enumerable.Range` and `Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault`:

```
List<List<string>> rotated = Enumerable.Range(0, PersonInfo.Max(list => list.Count))
 .Select(i => PersonInfo.Select(list => list.ElementAtOrDefault(i)).ToList())
 .ToList();
```

`PersonInfo.Max(list => list.Count)` returns the max-size of the lists. This will be the new size of the main list, in  this case 3. `Enumerable.Range` is like a for-loop. For every list it will now select all strings at these indexes. If the sizes are different you'll get `null`(because of `ElementAtOrDefault`).

If the lists had the same size you can apply the same query to get the original list back:

```
PersonInfo = Enumerable.Range(0, rotated.Max(list => list.Count))
 .Select(i => rotated.Select(list => list.ElementAtOrDefault(i)).ToList())
 .ToList();
```

As extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> Rotate<T>(this IEnumerable<IList<T>> sequences)
{
    var list = sequences as IList<IList<T>> ?? sequences.ToList();
    int maxCount = list.Max(l => l.Count);
    return Enumerable.Range(0, maxCount)
        .Select(i => list.Select(l => l.ElementAtOrDefault(i)).ToList());
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<IList<string>> rotated = PersonInfo.Rotate();
IEnumerable<IList<string>> rotatedPersonInfo = rotated.Rotate(); // append ToList to get the original list
```

Comment: @Oliver: why delete? Of course the lists must have the same size, but that is the case here. But thanks for noting, I've fixed my answer

Comment: I read it as `Min` not `Max` (duh) so I was referring to data loss rather than additional values.  Different none the less!

Answer (score 0):

This extends the Zip idea above to any number of lists. Zip will truncate the row lists to the smallest rank.

```
List<List<string>> PersonInfo = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>() {"John", "Peter", "Watson"},
    new List<string>() {"1000", "1001", "1002"},
    new List<string>() {"2000", "2001", "2002"},
    new List<string>() {"3000", "3001", "3002"}
};

var seed = Enumerable.Empty<List<string>>();
var transformed = PersonInfo.Aggregate(seed, (acc, r) =>
   acc.Any()
 ? acc.Zip(r, (row, nextElement) => { row.Add(nextElement); return row; })
 : r.Select(e => new List<string> { e }) //initialize target list using first row
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like:

```
var persons = Enumerable.Range(0, PersonInfo.First().Count()).Select(i => PersonInfo.Select(e => e[i]).ToList()).ToList();
```

or

```
var persons = Enumerable.Range(0, PersonInfo[0].Count()).Select(i => {
    return PersonInfo.Select(e => {
        return e[i];
    }).ToList();
}).ToList();
```

and check the result like below:

```
persons.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", p[0], p[1]));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
List<List<string>> PersonInfo = new List<List<string>>(){
new List<string>() {"John", "Peter", "Watson"},
new List<string>() {"1000", "1001", "1002"}};

List<List<string>> PivitedPersonInfo = new List<List<string>>();
for (int i = 0; i < PersonInfo.First().Count; i++)
{
    PivitedPersonInfo.Add(PersonInfo.Select(x => x.ElementAt(i)).ToList());
}
```