# Name values list to dictionary to import in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am stuck in a problem where I need to convert a list into Dictionary > BsonDocument to import in MongoDB.

The list has the name of column and the values to insert in that column. But I am getting key already exits exception as soon the compiler enter in loop. Any suggestion?

```
void Main()
{
    List<ListRow> myList = new List<ListRow>();
    myList.Add(new ListRow { columnName = "column1", results = new List<string> { "a1", "b1", "c1" } });
    myList.Add(new ListRow { columnName = "column2", results = new List<string> { "a2", "b2", "c2" } });
    myList.Add(new ListRow { columnName = "column3", results = new List<string> { "a3", "b3", "c3" } });

    List<BsonDocument> batch = new List<BsonDocument>();
    foreach (var row in myList)
    {
        var dictionary = row.results.ToDictionary(x => row.columnName, x => x);
        batch.Add(dictionary);
    }
    // Print batch
    // Add to MongoDB
}

public class ListRow
{
    public string columnName { get; set; }
    public List<string> results { get; set; }
}
```

Expected result to pull

[image]

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? is it var dictionary = row.results ...?

Comment: Yes the row.results is throwing error.

Comment: So, it seems that your data has duplicated keys. ToDictionary() will throw error in such case. You can use .GroupBy(x => rowColumnName) and loop the grouped collection

Comment: And i just saw that you are repeating the same key : row.results.ToDictionary(x => row.columnName, x => x); It's normal that you have this error

Comment: Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Can you show us the expected result in JSON format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. If I understand the problem correctly, you want to first transpose the matrix of

```
"a1", "b1", "c1"
"a2", "b2", "c2"
"a3", "b3", "c3"
```

than name the columns with column1, column2, column3, etc.. For the transpose problem I got [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39485441/1859959).

From there I worked out this solution, where I needed a root node, which is not clear how should look like from the question>

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ListRow> myList = new List<ListRow>
        {
            new ListRow {columnName = "column1", results = new List<string> {"a1", "b1", "c1"}},
            new ListRow {columnName = "column2", results = new List<string> {"a2", "b2", "c2"}},
            new ListRow {columnName = "column3", results = new List<string> {"a3", "b3", "c3"}}
        };

        var result = myList
            .SelectMany(listRow => listRow.results.Select((item, index) => new {item, index}))
            .GroupBy(i => i.index, i => i.item)
            .Select(g => g.Select((x, index) => new {Col = myList[index].columnName, Value = x})
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Col, x => x.Value))
            .ToList();

        BsonDocument batch = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> {{"root", result}}
            .ToBsonDocument();
        // {{ "root" : [{ "column1" : "a1", "column2" : "a2", "column3" : "a3" }, { "column1" : "b1", "column2" : "b2", "column3" : "b3" }, { "column1" : "c1", "column2" : "c2", "column3" : "c3" }] }}
        // or just
        BsonArray batchPart = BsonArray.Create(result);
        // {[{ "column1" : "a1", "column2" : "a2", "column3" : "a3" }, { "column1" : "b1", "column2" : "b2", "column3" : "b3" }, { "column1" : "c1", "column2" : "c2", "column3" : "c3" }]}
        // Print batch
        // Add to MongoDB
    }
}

public class ListRow
{
    public string columnName { get; set; }
    public List<string> results { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i need.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make an entry in the iteration. `ToDictionary` aims for create the whole dictionary.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ListRow> myList = new List<ListRow>
        {
            new ListRow {columnName = "column1", results = new List<string> {"a1", "b1", "c1"}},
            new ListRow {columnName = "column2", results = new List<string> {"a2", "b2", "c2"}},
            new ListRow {columnName = "column3", results = new List<string> {"a3", "b3", "c3"}}
        };

        BsonDocument batch = myList.ToDictionary(x => x.columnName, x => x.results).ToBsonDocument();
        // Print batch
        // Add to MongoDB
    }
}

public class ListRow
{
    public string columnName { get; set; }
    public List<string> results { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It convert complete list into single document. While I need to store each list result as separate document to pull via api. For example a1-a3 as document1, b1-b3 as document 2 etc. See expected result in my update.

Comment: Can you show us an example in JSON format. What you have written "separate document" for me, means `db.document1.find()` results in `[ "a1", "a2", "a3" ]`?

Answer (score 0):

Your key : row.columName is repeated when the list is flatten to a dictionary. You can try to generate an unique key for each list item.

```
    List<BsonDocument> batch = new List<BsonDocument>();
    foreach (var row in myList)
    {
        var i = 0;
        var dictionary = row.results.ToDictionary(x => $"{row.columnName}_{++i}", x => x);
        batch.Add(dictionary);
    }
```

Comment: columnName are already unique. I think the main problem was the misunderstanding how `ToDictionary` work. But yes. That is a viable solution too, if the `x => x` is really intended.