# Convert multi-dimensional collection to string with separator

Tags: c#, linq

As I was working on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224512/how-to-transpose-rows-of-string-into-columns-using-lists-in-a-foreach-nested-loo/63225112#63225112), I've written some code to convert a generic multi-dimensional collection to a string.

```
public static string ConvertToString<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> input, string columnSplit = "", string rowSplit = "\n")
{
    return string.Join(rowSplit, input.Select(r => string.Concat(string.Join(columnSplit, r.Select(c => c.ToString())))));
}
```

**Example Input**

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> input = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "R", "L", "R", "R" },
    new List<string> { "L", "R", "V", "R" },
    new List<string> { "L", "R", "V", "R" },
    new List<string> { "R", "L", "L", "R" },
};
```

**Desired Output**

```
RLRR
LRVR
LRVR
RLLR
```

Although the code works, I don't find the solution to be elegant with the fact that it requires a `string.Join` inside a `string.Concat` inside a `Select`. Is there a way to simplify this solution.

Comment: Why you're wrapping Join with Concat? Looks like redundancy.

Comment: When I do `string.Concat(columnSplit, r.Select(c => c.ToString()))`, it only joins the `columnSplit` once, then returns Enumerable ToString, which isn't what I wanted.

Comment: Consider the answer, that is exactly what i mean.

Comment: @aepot After looking at Keith's answer, I now realise my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work without the concat and the select....

```
public static string ConvertToString<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> input, string columnSplit = "", string rowSplit = "\n")
{
  return string.Join(rowSplit, input.Select(r => string.Join(columnSplit, r)));
}
```

works with:

```
 IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> input = new List<List<string>>
            {
                new List<string> { "R", "L", "R", "R" },
                new List<string> { "L", "R", "V", "R" },
                new List<string> { "L", "R", "V", "R" },
                new List<string> { "R", "L", "L", "R" },
            };
```

and:

```
 IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> nums = new List<List<int>>
            {
                new List<int> { 1,2,3,4},
                new List<int> { 5,6,7,8},
            };
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't do this in the first place, seems dumb that I missed it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: also don't need the select

Answer (score 1):

Since you're defining extensions anyway, why not go all the way?

```
public static string ConvertToString<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> input, string columnSplit = "", string rowSplit = "\n") =>
    input.Select(r => r.ConvertToString(columnSplit)).ConvertToString(rowSplit);
    
public static string ConvertToString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, string split = "") => 
    string.Join(split, input.Select(i => i.ToString()));
```

Comment: This is also very neat.

Answer (score 0):

These are some nasty methods I did

```
public static string ToStringEnumeration(this IEnumerable source)
{
    return ToStringEnumeration(source, EnumerationMode.NewLineEach, null);
}

public enum EnumerationMode
{
    NewLineEach,
    Separator,
}

public static string ToStringEnumeration(this IEnumerable source, EnumerationMode mode, string separator = null)
{
    return ToStringEnumeration(source, mode, separator, null, null);
}

public static string ToStringEnumeration(this IEnumerable source, EnumerationMode mode, string separator, IFormatProvider provider, string format)
{
    if (source is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    if (source.IsEmpty())
        return "";

    var sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        var strElement = format is null ? element.ToString() : string.Format(provider, format, element);
        sBuilder.Append(strElement);

        if (mode == EnumerationMode.NewLineEach)
            sBuilder.AppendLine();
        else if (mode == EnumerationMode.Separator)
            sBuilder.Append(separator);
    }

    var sLength = separator?.Length ?? 1;

    if (mode == EnumerationMode.NewLineEach) //quit /n/r
        sBuilder.Remove(sBuilder.Length - 2, 2);
    else if (mode == EnumerationMode.Separator)
        sBuilder.Remove(sBuilder.Length - sLength, sLength);

    return sBuilder.ToString();
}
```