# How do I add the sum of the columns of a 2d List<> in a 1d List<> in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I basically want to go through the 2d List<> and deposit the sum of the items in a column to a 1d List. So far have a double for loop but I cant figure out the logic. Any help with how I can start to contruct it logically would be helpful. Thank you. This is the code I have so far:

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! To improve your chances of getting an answer please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please update your post to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Post how you trying to do and the incorrect results you have.

Comment: Thank you for ur input. I edited my code so hopefully its clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

So if you have this:

```
var grid = new List<List<int>> {
  new() { 1,2 },
  new() { 3,4 }
}
```

You can do:

```
grid.Pivot().Select(c => c.Sum());
```

And you'll get an enumerable that is `{ 4, 6 }` (1+3 and 2+4)

You can get Pivot from fubo's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484996/rotate-transposing-a-listliststring-using-linq-c-sharp) (or choose any one of the other suggested transforms)

If I misunderstood and you wanted {3,5} just skip the Pivot part