# Is there a LINQ operator to do this?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know if there's a LINQ operator to do this:

```
var one = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var two = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var combined = new [] { one, two };

var result = Operator(combined);

Console.WriteLine(result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new [] { "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", null, "D" }));
```

If short, it should act like if every sequence was a row in a matrix. And after that, it should:

1. Transpose the matrix (rotate it)
2. It should push every "cell" in the matrix, returning the corresponding item, or default if the cell is empty.

I mean, graphically:

```
A, B, C
A, B, C, D

<Transpose>

A, A
B, B
C, C
D

result => A, A, B, B, C, C, D, null
```

#### NOTICE

**`Operator` should work on `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`**

As you can see, the `Operator` I'm interested in, uses `combined`, so it accepts should `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` (like `SelectMany`).

Comment: How exactly would you describe what that operation is doing?

Comment: join probably works

Comment: Next question: you have a trailing comma on `one`, which is not a syntax error but potentially evidence of a mistake... does `one` have 3 elements, or does it have 4 elements and you missed a `null` at the end?

Comment: Next-next question: why does `Operator` take a `string[][]` parameter and not two `string[]` parameters?

Comment: Your question is a yes/no question. The answer is "no" (although `Zip` is close). If this question were to be reopened (and I say that because there's currently a vote to reopen it), that wouldn't be much of an answer. Try writing the code for such an operator and then post that if you have trouble making it work.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1190657/109941

Comment: Your question gets more specific with each edit. So you want it to work with an arbitrary collection of `IEnumerable<T>` instead of exactly two string arrays now. I'll update my answer tomorrow or Monday, but it won't be much of a change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the result independent of the number of arrays the function should loop trough all arrays and keep returning until all enumerations are exhausted:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Transpose<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    var enumerators = source.Select(e => e.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
    try
    {
        var next = false;
        do
        {
            var results = enumerators.Select(enr =>
            {
                if (enr.MoveNext())
                {
                    return enr.Current;
                }
                return default;
            }).ToList();
            next = results.Any(e => !Equals(default, e));
            if (next)
            {
                yield return results;
            }
        }
        while (next);
    }
    finally
    {
        Array.ForEach(enumerators, e => e.Dispose());
    }
}
```

Now you can use any number of arrays:

```cs
var one = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var two = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var three = new[] { "U", "V","W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
var combined = new[] { one, three, two };
var result = combined.Transpose().SelectMany(e => e).ToList();
```

This will result in

```
"A","U","A","B","V","B","C","W","C",null,"X","D",null,"Y",null,null,"Z",null
```

Filtering the null values is trivial.

(Courtesy [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39485398/861716) for the basic idea, but only working for arrays of equal length).

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit hard keeping up with your changing specs.  Originally, it was a pair of string arrays.  I changed that to be a pair of arrays of `T` in my answer.

Then you wrote in a comment that "oh, no, I meant N sequences".  Finally, after reading that, I noticed that you'd updated your question to ask about N collections expressed as `IEnumerable<T>`.

In the mean time, I pointed out that my original answer would work well for N arrays with minimal change.  So, here goes:

**For N Arrays**

I use the `params` keyword to remove the need for your *combined* variable.  The `params` keyword will *compose* some or all of the parameters of a method into an array.

Here's a method that can take N arrays:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> KnitArrays<T>(params T[][] arrays) 
{
    var maxLen = (from array in arrays select array.Length).Max();
    for (var i = 0; i < maxLen; i++)
    {
        foreach( var array in arrays)
        {
            yield return array.Length > i ? array[i] : default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty much the same logic as the original answer.  The test code looks the same as well:

```
var one = new[] { "A1", "B1", "C1" };
var two = new[] { "A2", "B2", "C2", "D2" };
var three = new[] { "A3", "B3" };

var knittedArray = KnitArrays(one, two, three);
List<string> result = knittedArray.ToList();
WriteCollectionContents(result);
```

Where `WriteCollectionContents` spits out the contents of the collection.  In this case:

```
"A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", null, null, "D2", null,
```

**For N Lists and/or Arrays**

It turns out that the same basic code can work with `IList<T>`, i.e., for both `List<T>` and `T[]`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> KnitILists<T>(params IList<T>[] ilists)
{
    var maxLen = (from ilist in ilists select ilist.Count).Max();
    for (var i = 0; i < maxLen; i++)
    {
        foreach (var ilist in ilists)
        {
            yield return ilist.Count > i ? ilist[i] : default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

The test code for this also looks pretty similar - though note the mix or arrays and lists:

```
var one = new[] { "A1", "B1", "C1" };
var two = new[] { "A2", "B2", "C2", "D2" };
var list3 = new List<string> { "A3", "B3" };

var knittedLists = KnitILists(one, two, list3);
result = knittedLists.ToList();
WriteCollectionContents(result);
```

With exactly the same result:

```
"A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", null, null, "D2", null,
```

The reason it works with `IList<T>` is that that interface has a `Count` property and an `Item` indexer.  If you go to `ICollection<T>` the `Count` property stays, but you lose the `Item` indexer.

Once you get to `IEnumerable<T>`, both the `Count` property and the `Item` indexer are gone.  The only thing you can do with an `IEnumerable` is to iterate through it.  As a result, the logic needs to be very different.

I might get around to coming up with a solution.  However, it will likely look very similar to @gertarnold's answer.

I'm looking foreword to your upcoming comment about how you really meant for this to work with multi-dimensional arrays as well.

**Original answer follows**

How about something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> KnitArrays<T>(T[] first, T[] second) 
{
    var maxLen = Math.Max(first.Length, second.Length);
    for (var i = 0; i < maxLen; i++)
    {
        yield return first.Length > i ? first[i] : default(T);
        yield return second.Length > i ? second[i] : default(T);
    }
}
```

Testing this with:

```
var one = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var two = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

var knittedArray = KnitArrays(one, two);
List<string> result = knittedArray.ToList();
```

yields a list that looks like what you are asking.  Note that I just return a non-materialized IEnumerable since you were asking about LINQ.

Comment: Thanks, but that works for 2 sequences. I would like it to work for `n`. I wasn't explicit enough in the OP, but if you notice it, you'll see that the `Operator` function uses `composed` instead :)

Comment: No, you were not explicit _at all_ about that. If you use the `params` keyword, you can make the parameter to the function be an array of arrays of `T`. Then use LINQ to get the max length of all the arrays and put an inner `foreach` inside the `for` loop with a single `yield return` statement inside the `foreach`. It _should just work_ (though it will likely take a try or three with the debugger to get it right)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _`composed`_ in your comment.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `combined`.

Comment: @SuperJMN: I updated my answer to handle N arrays, and again to handle N arrays or lists.  Note that I got rid of the need to have a `combined` (or, `composed`) variable or operation (by using the standard `params` keyword)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Max(one.Count(), two.Count()))
.SelectMany(n => new[] { one.ElementAtOrDefault(n), two.ElementAtOrDefault(n) });
```

result

```
["A","A","B","B","C","C",null,"D"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that works for 2 sequences. I would like it to work for n. I wasn't explicit enough in the OP, but if you notice it, you'll see that the Operator function uses composed instead :)

Comment: @SuperJMN It is quite easy to adapt this code for N sequences, but after this you will tell that you need code for N+1.