# How to perform a matrix transform function on a lists of lists c#

Tags: c#, transformation, emgucv, nested-lists

I have a Lists of lists of type MCvPoint3D32f. An MCvPoint3D32f point is an EmguCV type 3D point that contains (x, y, z) float values. This list stores 4 corner points of a square. E.g. Square 0 will have 4 corner points Square[0][0], Square[0][1.]..Square[0][3] etc.

The order of the corners stored is not consistent with the order I want. For example the corner points stored in the Square 1 contains corner points of Square 3, Square 2 of Square 6 etc. A matrix transformation is what I want to do on my list.

I'm trying to do that, but since this isn't a normal array but a list of lists. I'm not accessing or setting the values in a correct way.I get a out of bounds array range error. Is there a better way to achieve what i'm trying to do?

[image: The matrix]

```
 List<List<MCvPoint3D32f>> tempList = new List<List<MCvPoint3D32f>>();
 SortMatrixIndex(Matrix);
 private void SortMatrixIndex(List<List<MCvPoint3D32f>> matrix)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Count; i++)
        {
          if (i == 0 || i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 8)
           {
                tempList[i] = matrix[i];
           }
          else if (i == 5)
          {
                tempList[i] = matrix[i];
                matrix[i] = matrix[i + 2];
                matrix[i + 2] = tempList[i];
          }
          else
          {
                tempList[i] = matrix[i];
                matrix[i] = matrix[i * 3];
                matrix[i * 3] = tempList[i];
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Does not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950495/linq-swap-columns-into-rows answer your question?

Comment: I dont think so. I'm not even understanding what that code is doing. But i want to swap the inner elements of my squares. ie. the 4 corner points stored in Square[1] to Square[3] etc.

Comment: Basically I want to swap the inner elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best approach to solve the above problem, since its pretty much hard-coded for 3x3 matrix but works for now.

```
 private void TransposeMatrix(List<List<MCvPoint3D32f>> matrix)
 {
     //This case applies to both N and W, however N needs column swapping too
     for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Count; i++)
       {
          tempList.Add(new List<MCvPoint3D32f>());

           if (i == 1 || i == 2)
           {
               tempList[i] = matrix[i];
               matrix[i] = matrix[i * 3];
               matrix[i * 3] = tempList[i];   
           }
           else if (i == 5)
           {
               tempList[i] = matrix[i];
               matrix[i] = matrix[i + 2];
               matrix[i + 2] = tempList[i];
           }
           else
           {
               tempList[i] = matrix[i];
           }
        }

        tempList.Clear();
        this.squareMatt = matrix;
    }
```